# Unable to import 'import_export'

Tags: django, import, admin, pylint, django-import-export

I am developing an app in Django.
I have a model named `glossary_entry` and I want to be able to use the import_export widget for it (see image for example).

[image: import_export widget]

So I have read the docs and acted as follows:
I have already run

```
pip install django-import-export
```

added to settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'import_export',
```

run:

```
pip freeze>requirements.txt
```

And in my admin.py I have:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import glossary_entry 

from import_export import resources
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin


class glossary_entry_resource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model=glossary_entry

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(glossary_entry)
```

The problem is that when I run the server, I get

> Connection negated by 127.0.0.1

But even before that, in my VS code editor, i get an error underlined at lines

```
from import_export import resources
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin
```

which tells:

> Unable to import 'import_export'pylint(import-error)

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you want to  export your models using template or admin panel .?

Comment: I want to start by doing it by admin. Later I want to implement a template that allows users to upload csv files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import glossary_entry 

from import_export import resources
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin

class glossary_entryAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):   # FOR ADMIN IMPORT EXPORT ONLY 
    pass


admin.site.register(glossary_entry, glossary_entryAdmin)   #  FOR ADMIN IMPORT EXPORT ONLY
```

And go through docs https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Thanks! now it works! I actually forgot to register the glossary_entry_Admin class

Comment: Np it happens just  go through the documentation.

Comment: However, even if the widget has appeared, my VS studio code is going on showing an underlined error under the lines "from import_export import resources" "from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin" – weird...

Comment: I think the is some problem with the configuration of the editor. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I’m happy to help